# How should I create custom UITableCellView programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am in a situation in which I need to create custom table cells. I have subclassed UITableViewCell:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *icon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timestamp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *email;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *phone;

...
```

Icon, name and timestamp will always be required.  Email and phone are optional labels.  I initially looked into just hiding the 'optional' labels but that does not remove the space that they take up.  So I am looking into building this tableviewcell programatically.

2 things:

1. I cannot find anywhere that builds this programatically with constraints so I am little stumped on how to even get started.
2. I have created some of it in IB, i.e. since image, name and timestamp will always be there I thought maybe this would be better to put in IB.  Then just build out the other labels underneath name and timestamp:

[image]

I tried to create a new initMethod:

```
- (id)initWithUser:(User *) user {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"userCell"];
    if (self) {
        // configure required stuff
        [self.icon setImage:[PersonImage imageForTimestamp:user.timestamp]];
        self.name.text = user.name;
        self.timestamp.text = user.timestamp;

        if (user.email != nil) {
          //add email label with constraint tied to timestamp
        }

        if (user.phone != nil) {
          //add phone label with constraint tied to timestamp or email
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

I set identifier to userCell in IB.  However it does not seem to have my required labels.  Can I do this?  Is it a good idea?  How do I create the labels with the correct position?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with interface builder but I would suspect your outlets need to be `strong` not `weak` or else they're going to be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that cells in an table view aren't `init`d every time. They get dequeued in order to save the overhead of creating a new cell every time. You will customize the data for the cell you're subclassing in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: So I have to create the custom cell in tableview class not tableviewcell class?  Seems backwards. Why would you ever subclass UITableViewCell.

Comment: The method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a `UITableViewDataSource` method NOT a `UITableView` method. You implement the data source methods in a controller. Therefore, in the controller you tell the cell what data to use. The cell takes the data you pass to it and determines how to actually present it. It conforms to MVC quite well.

Comment: Instead of implementing the method `-initWithUser:` create a method `-setUser:`. Then in the .m you can do everything you are currently doing in `if (self)`. Then wherever you are implementing `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can call `[cell setUser:userYouWantForTheCell]` after dequeueing the cell.